# boost asio async write handler calling itself

Tags: c++, boost, asynchronous, tcp, boost-asio

This question is in connection with another previous question of mine.

Can a boost::asio::async_write handler function called upon completion of the write operation itself engaging in a write operation cause problems ?

example

```
 void on_write(const boost::system::error_code & error_code){
   if (! error_code){
     std::string some_data_to_transfer("hello world");
     std::vector<char> vec_buf(some_data_to_transfer.begin(),some_data_to_transfer.end());
     boost::asio::async_write(this->socket,boost::asio::buffer(vec_buf),
     boost::asio::transfer_exactly(vec_buf.size()),
     boost::bind(&Server::on_write,this->shared_from_this(),
     boost::asio::placeholders::error));
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it will not cause any problems. In fact, there are numerous reasons to do it that way.  On example is a TCP based file server, where as each part of the file is transferred, you read the next part of the file and write it to the network.

One thing to note:   You've got undefined behavior, because the buffer you are using (vec_buf) is destructed before the call completes.  Typically, you would make vec_buf a member of the class in question.